# How do I enable the "extra" stuff in the OpenPublic distribution?

Tags: distributions

[OpenPublic](http://drupal.org/project/openpublic) is a Drupal distribution that is supposed to be for NGOs (and government).  I've downloaded and installed the distribution as a tarball from their site using the big [download button](http://openpublicapp.com/).

The tarball is about twice the size of a basic Drupal 7.22 core tarball, so I assume there are some extra stuff included in this distribution.

However, after following the instructions for installation (they refer to the standard instructions for installing Drupal 7), I am looking at a completely plain vanilla Drupal 7 website.  No additional themes, no additional content types, no additional functionality.

I've been hunting high and low for documentation for what to do post-installation with this distribution and come up with nothing.

There is a support group for the distribution at groups.drupal.org, but it is not very responsive, for instance, [this question](http://groups.drupal.org/node/277793) was asked on Jan 18th, with no reply yet.

I am asking here, hoping that someone here is familiar with this distribution and can provide me with the recipe of how about to "unlock" whatever this distribution has to offer, or—even better—provide a link to the missing manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've just installed the wrong profile. At the first step of the installation you get a choice like

[image]

Once you choose OpenPublic and follow the installation through, you won't have a vanilla Drupal install any more. For example your home page looks like this:

[image]

Don't forget it's still in beta so you're likely to see warnings/notices around the place; I wouldn't recommend using it for a production site yet. It's also pretty sluggish compared to a normal Drupal install so make sure you profile it before deciding whether or not to use it.

Comment: Doh! (I just had a Homer moment ...)